# Publish to the Discussions tab of a fanpage from an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to create a new topic on the discussion tab on a fanpage from inside an facebook app? Can the graph api access the discussion tab?

Answer (score 1):

no it can't. The Facebook Graph Api is not designed for such purpose. The discussion tab is a free space for discussion, not for integration with any app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought so.